# How can i install ubuntu on my ntfs hdd without formatting?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ntfs, format

My hdd is just one partition in ntfs (500gb) and 430 gb is used by my photos/movies/music etc which I never will want to lose. Actually I installed Ubuntu on a usb flash drive (using it right now) but it is too slow that way. But my problem is : My computer is damaged ( maybe chipset or but not sure) and none of the windows versions (xp,vista,7) works on my pc. I get blue screen error as soon as windows startup logo shows. But Ubuntu just works flawless. That means I cannot use wubi. I wanted to shrink my hdd without losing data (which can be done in windows) but found nothing about that on Ubuntu forums. Is this possible? Or install Ubuntu on my ntfs filesystem?

Note : I don't have chance to backup 400 gbs of data.

Sorry for my question if it's written a bit compex. I hope you get the point and someone has an idea ;)

Comment: possibly also http://askubuntu.com/questions/55441/install-ubuntu-on-a-ntfs-partition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install Ubuntu on a NTFS partition](/q/55441/175814)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install Linux on NTFS as NTFS does not support UNIX user/group file permissions. You can try to use `gparted` on the Ubuntu CD to resize the partition, but you run the risk of losing data. I think you should buy a 1TB portable USB3 hard drive. They often sell for around $70-100 on Newegg/Amazon.