# Install Ubuntu on a loop device?

Tags: system-installation, mount, ubiquity, loop-device

I used grub2 to boot the Ubuntu ISO file from my hard disk (without burning it to a DVD or a flash drive), but I don't want to install Ubuntu to a partition on my hard disk; instead I want to install it to a disk image (.img)file.

So, I created an .img file (using `dd`) and then I mounted the `.img` file through multiple ways:

1. Using `kpartx` (which mounts to `/dev/mapper` devices).
2. Using `losetup` (which mounts to `/dev/loopX` devices).

But when I run the Ubuntu installer (`ubuquity`) the installer doesn't seem to recognize the loop device as a hard disk, so I only get `/dev/sdXX` device and can't see loop devices!

Now, I didn't try to mount the image using the `mount` command, but I'm sure it will show the same issue, because as far as I know that `losetup` uses `mount` to mount the files.

So I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to make ubiquity detect "loop devices" as hard disks?
2. Can I mount `.img` files to `/dev/sdXX` devices (instead of the normal `/dev/loopX`)?

Answer (score 2):

I have written [a blog post about this](http://hopkinsdev.blogspot.com/2017/01/installing-linux-ubuntu-on-existing.html).

Basically you just need to create a virtual block device at `/dev/sdX`, and mount your LOFS on it. Then you can run the installer and install Ubuntu on it. But please note that you cannot install GRUB directly on it (and there is no point to do so).

Comment: To avoid link rot, please summarize the steps here.

Comment: @Oxwivi  The summarized steps already written in the second paragraph of this answer.

Comment: Do you think it is possibile to install grub on USB stick addressing a loopback file on the internal disk (so we can avoid to modify the original Windows bootloader)?

Comment: @AntonioPetricca Of course. You can install GRUB on your USB stick, making it acting like some sort of a "bootloader stick" which boots some partitions/LOFS on the internal disk.