# Do I need to make a FAT32 partition to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on my laptop with following configuration:

- Hp Envy x360
- Hard Disk: 1 TB
- RAM: 16GB

I have created a separate partion of 300GB for Ubuntu which is NTFS. I have downloaded Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS iso file and will install using bootable pendrive.

I searched on the internet and read that to install Ubuntu you must have a FAT32 partition. I am new to Ubuntu and I am unable to change the separate partition in Windows 10 to FAT32. Will I be able to install Ubuntu on my machine? If yes, what are my options?

Comment: Where did you read that? Ubuntu uses ext4, not FAT32. And you don't need to create the partition ahead of time; you can do it during the installation.

Comment: Hey @wjandrea I read on following link https://askubuntu.com/questions/55441/install-ubuntu-on-a-ntfs-partition

Comment: I don't see any mention of FAT32 on that thread. And that question is irrelevant anyway, cause unless you have specific requirements, you should use the default filesystem, ext4. At least as a beginner.

Comment: @wjandrea I actually saw a video of installing ubuntu on youtube. In that video they chose FAT32 option while to make pendrive bootable so I started searching whether I need parition as FAT32 too. I am really to new this so I apologize if you find my question irrelevant. While creating pend drive bootable I have to choose NTFS or FAT32 which one do you suggest?

Comment: Looking at [the official guide](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#4), it looks like you should use FAT32 for the USB drive. But if you use Rufus, FAT32 is already the default, so you don't need to touch it. Anyway, that's just for the installer (USB drive), not the partition on which you install Ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not saying your question is irrelevant, but the one you linked. It talks about specifically needing to install Ubuntu on NTFS.

Comment: It's okay @wjandrea..Thank you very much I will go through the guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the disk space for installing Ubuntu has been selected, the Ubuntu installer will select the correct partitioning format (ext4) automatically no matter what the original partition format is. FAT32, NTFS or any other format, it doesn't matter to the Ubuntu installer, it will format the Ubuntu partition(s) to ext4 by default.